# UITextView can't change size with auto layout

Tags: ios, uitextview, setneedsdisplay, contentsize, sizetofit

I have a `XIB` file containing a view with a `UITextView` as subview. This textView is 30px high, because it should resize according to it's content.

So I set the text programmatically, call `-sizeToFit` and reconfigure the frame of the textView and its superview:

```
[_textView setText:[contents objectForKey:@"body"]];
[_textView sizeToFit];

CGSize txtSize = _textView.contentSize;
txtSize.height = _textView.frame.size.height;
_textView.contentSite = txtSize;

CGRect superFrame = _textView.superView.frame;
superFrame += _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.superView.frame = superFrame;
```

The superView actually does resize correctly. Also, when logging the text views frame and content size, on the console it appears to be okay (about 1200px high).

But the textView **is** still just 30px high on the screen. Also calling `-setNeedsLayout` did not do the trick.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug i ran into a couple of days ago. It seems that UITextView will cut off a part of the text no matter the height if its scroll is disabled.

A solution that works in certain situations is:

```
[_textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_textView setText:text];
[_textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

I have reported this bug to Apple, but I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I'm searching for. I want to adjust the actual size of the textView according to it's content. I have a view that displays an article. And this should get longer and longer. So I don't scroll in the textView, but it's superview

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the same problem I had. I wanted to scroll the superview and because of that disabled scroll on the text view. The solution that I used in the end is that I left scrolling enabled since I'm already resizing the text view.